# Sorting multiple div with classes

Tags: jquery, class, filter

So I have a list of div that have several classes attached to each (mon thurs s1 s2 dance sing voice ect.) I want to set up a filter system that allows users to select a class and hide the others. It would be great to select multiple classes and show what is selected.

My HTML

```
 <!-- Class Info -->
 <!-- Fliter Btn -->
  <button class="clearBtn btn" id="clearBtn">Clear Filter</button>
  <button class="filterBtn btn" id="filterBtn">Filter</button>
   <!-- Fliter Btn -->

  <!-- Fliter -->
   <div class="container" id="filterBoxes">
     <div class="row " id="filterField">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
          <button id="actBtn" class="actBtn btn">Acting Classes</button>
 </div>


 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
 <button id="danceBtn" class="danceBtn btn">Dance Classes</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
 <button id="voiceBtn" class="voiceBtn btn">Voice Classes</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
 <button id="tchBtn" class="tchBtn btn">Tech Classes</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
 <button id="monBtn" class="monBtn btn">Monday Classes</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
 <button id="thursBtn" class="thursBtn btn">Thursday Classes</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
 <button id="s1Btn" class="s1Btn btn">Session 1 Classes</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
 <button id="s2Btn" class="s2Btn btn">Session 2 Classes</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
 <button id="g2-6Btn" class="g2-6Btn btn">Grade 2 - 6 Classes</button>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 fliterBox">
 <button id="g7-12Btn" class="g7-12Btn btn">Grade 7 - 12 Classes</button>
 </div>

  </div>
  </div> 
  <!-- Fliter -->


   <!-- Acting -->
   <div class="container">
  <h3 class="classTitle acting">Acting Classes</h3>
   <!--Class-->
   <div class="row classes"> <!--Class-->
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3  acting g2-6 thurs s1 class" id="clown">
        <h4 class="className">Clowning Skills</h4> 
        <p class="classInfo">Grades 2 – 6<br />Thursdays Session 1</p>
         <!-- course Discription -->
     <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-
      multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-
      toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" 
        href="#collapseOne2">Course Discription </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse in 
          courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          <p class="classDis">Are you always looking for ways to entertain 
         and amaze?  Do you love to make people laugh?  Add to your 
         hilarious skills each week as Ms Amy Arpan teaches you the tricks 
         of the trade, including juggling!</p>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
     <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
  </div>
  <!--Class-->
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 acting g7-12 mon s2 class" id="improve1a">
    <h4 class="className">Improve 1A</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 7 – 12<br />Mondays Session 2</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3" role="tablist" aria-
    multiselectable="true" >
      <div class="panel panelStyle">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-
    toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne3">Course 
    Description &amp; Prerequisite </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne3" class="panel-collapse collapse in 
   courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          <p class="classDis">
              Learn challenging improv games and take your comic timing to 
    the next level.</p>
              <p><em>(Pre-req: All students must have at least one previous 
    show experience)</em></p>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
     <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
  </div>
<!--Class-->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 acting g2-6 mon s2 class" id="improve1b">
    <h4 class="className">Improve 1B</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 2 – 6<br />Mondays Session 2</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion4" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" >
      <div class="panel panelStyle">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne4">Course Description &amp; Prerequisite </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne4" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          <p class="classDis">
            Time to tickle the funny bone! This class is perfect for any young budding comic. Learn new short form improv games each week and start your path to comic genius.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
     <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
</div>
<!--Class-->
  </div><!-- acting classes section-->
  </div><!-- acting container-->

  <!-- Singing Classes -->
  <h3 class="classTitle sing">Vocie Studio</h3>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row col-centered">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g7-12 mon s2 sing class" id="voice studio 1A">
    <h4 class="className">Voice Studio 1A</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 7 – 12<br />Mondays Session 2</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion5" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne5">Course Discription </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne5" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          <p class="classDis">Are you looking to learn proper singing technique or simply brush up on your vocal skills? The Voice Studio is the right class for you! Join our studio to practice good vocal habits, fundamental singing technique and understand how the vocal anatomy works to give you the best tone quality. You will be introduced to the art song and folk song genre.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
     <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
  </div>
  <!--Class-->
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g2-6 mon s1 sing class" id="voiceStudio1b">
    <h4 class="className">Voice Studio 1B</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 2 – 6<br />Mondays Session 1</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion6" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne6">Course Discription </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne6" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p class="classDis">Are you looking to learn proper singing technique or simply brush up on your vocal skills? The Voice Studio is the right class for you! Join our studio to practice good vocal habits, fundamental singing technique and understand how the vocal anatomy works to give you the best tone quality. You will be introduced to the art song and folk song genre.</p></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- Corse description -->
       <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
  </div><!-- Class-->
  <!--Class-->
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g7-12 thurs s2 sing class" id="voiceStudio2b">
    <h4 class="className">Voice Studio 2B</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 2 – 6<br />Thursdays Session 2</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion7" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne7">Course Discription &amp; Prerequisite </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne7" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p class="classDis">Continue your vocal journey and re-discover your voice in this next level of The Voice Studio. You will continue to develop your singing skills with an emphasis in tone quality and resonance. Students will expand their repertoire by adding music from the Broadway and jazz genres.</p> <p><em>(Students must take The Voice Studio 1A/1B, or audition, to be in this class.)</em></p></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
   <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
</div><!-- Class-->
<!--Class-->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g7-12 thurs s2 sing class" id="duets1a">
    <h4 class="className">Duets 1A</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 7 – 12<br />Thursdays Session 2</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion8" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne8">Course Discription </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne8" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p class="classDis">Do you love the harmonious sound of the Broadway duet? Would you like to feel confident singing with another person? This Duets class will be the perfect fit! Learn how to balance and blend with another singer and confidently sing harmonies. This is a skill that is critical to the musical theatre experience!</p></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
  <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
</div><!-- Class-->
</div> <!-- sing row --->
</div><!-- Sing contaner -->




     <!-- Dance Classes -->
  <h3 class="classTitle dance">Dance Classes</h3>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row col-centered">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g7-12 mon s1 dance class" id="hiphop1a">
    <h4 class="className">Hip-Hop 1A</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 7 – 12<br />Mondays Session 1</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion9" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne9">Course Discription </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne9" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
          <p class="classDis">Hip hop is an urban street dance style that infuses breaking, popping, locking, b-boy, funk and jazz. This high energy class is for beginners in 7th- 12th grades.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
     <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
 </div>
 <!--Class-->
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g2-6 thurs s2 dance class" id="hipHop1b">
    <h4 class="className">Hip-Hop 1B</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 2 – 6<br />Thursdays Session 2</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion10" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne10">Course Discription </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne10" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p class="classDis">Hip hop is an urban street dance style that infuses breaking, popping, locking, b-boy, funk and jazz. This high energy class is for beginners in 2nd- 6th grades.</p></div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div><!-- Corse description -->
    <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
 </div><!-- Class-->
 <!--Class-->
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g7-12 thurs s2 dance class" id="tapB1a">
    <h4 class="className">Tap Basics 1A</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 7 – 12<br />Thursdays Session 2</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion11" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne11">Course Discription </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne11" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p class="classDis">This class, open to students in grades 7th and up, is designed for the development of basic tap technique and terminology highlighting the importance of rhythm and sound.  The class will focus on classic Broadway style tap dance. No prior tap experience is required. We will work to create a percussive instrument out of our feet. Purchase of tap shoes is required prior to start of class. Preferably a black tied tap shoe that can be picked up at any dance shoe store.</p></div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div><!-- Corse description -->
<!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
</div><!-- Class-->
<!--Class-->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g2-6 thurs s1 dance class" id="TapB1b">
    <h4 class="className">Tap Basics 1B</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 2 – 6<br />Thursdays Session 1</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion12" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne12">Course Discription </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne12" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p class="classDis">This class, open to students in 2nd to 6th grades, is designed for the development of basic tap technique and terminology highlighting the importance of rhythm and sound.  We will go slow in our exploration of beginner tap technique. The class will focus on classic Broadway style tap dance. We will work to create a percussive instrument out of our feet. Purchase of tap shoes is required prior to start of class. Preferably a black tied tap shoe that can be picked up at any dance shoe store.</p></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
  <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
 </div><!-- Class-->
    <!--Class-->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g7-12 mon s2 dance class" id="Tap2a">
    <h4 class="className">Tap 2A</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 7 – 12<br />Mondays Session 2</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion13" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne13">Course Discription &amp; Prerequisite </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne13" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p class="classDis">Tap 2A is an upper level tap class for those who completed Tap 1A. Tap is designed to develop rhythm, musicality, and coordination.</p>
              <p><em>(Pre-req: Tap 1A, or Tap 1B and 6th grade placement, or a placement audition)</em></p></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
  <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
</div><!-- Class-->
    <!--Class-->
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 g7-12 mon s1 dance class" id="Tap2b">
    <h4 class="className">Tap 2B</h4> 
    <p class="classInfo">Grades 7 – 12<br />Mondays Session 1</p>
    <!-- course Discription -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion14" role="tablist" aria-
multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
          <h4 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a data-
toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne14">Course 
Discription </a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne14" class="panel-collapse collapse in courseCollapse">
          <div class="panel-body"><p class="classDis">Tap 2B is an upper level tap class for those who completed Tap 1B. Tap is designed to develop rhythm, musicality, and coordination.</p><p><em> (Pre-req: Tap 1B or a placement audition)!</em></p></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- Corse description -->
  <!-- add to cart Button-->
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 cartBtn">
                <button class="addToCartBtnReg hidden">Add To Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- add to cart Button-->
</div><!-- Class-->
</div> <!-- dance row --->
</div><!-- dance contaner -->
```

Jquery

```
    $('.actBtn').click(function(){
  // change btn color

    $('#actBtn').removeClass('actBtn').addClass('btnSelect');
   // hide other classes    

      if($('.sing ,.tech ,.dance').hasClass('hidden')){
   $('.sing ,.tech ,.dance').removeClass('hidden');}
    else {$('.sing ,.tech ,.dance').addClass('hidden');}
  });
  $('.voiceBtn').click(function(){
        // change btn color
      $('#voiceBtn').removeClass('voiceBtn').addClass('btnSelect');
// hide other classes       
       $('.acting ,.tech ,.dance').addClass('hidden');
});
$('.danceBtn').click(function(){
    // change btn color
       $('#danceBtn').removeClass('danceBtn').addClass('btnSelect');
// hide other classes       
      $('.sing ,.tech ,.acting').addClass('hidden');
});
$('.tchBtn').click(function(){
    // change btn color
      $('#tchBtn').removeClass('tchBtn').addClass('btnSelect');
// hide other classes       
      $('.sing ,.acting ,.dance').addClass('hidden');
});
$('.s1Btn').click(function(){
// change btn color
      $('#s1Btn').removeClass('s1Btn').addClass('btnSelect');
// hide other classes       
       $('.s2').addClass('hidden');
});
$('.s2Btn').click(function(){
    // change btn color
      $('#s2Btn').removeClass('s2Btn').addClass('btnSelect');
// hide other classes       
      $('.s1').addClass('hidden');
});
$('.monBtn').click(function(){
    // change btn color
      $('#monBtn').removeClass('monBtn').addClass('btnSelect');
// hide other classes       
       if($('.thurs').hasClass('hidden')){
       $('.thurs').removeClass('hidden');}
    else {$('.thurs').addClass('hidden');}
});
$('.thursBtn').click(function(){
// change btn color
       $('#thursBtn').removeClass('thursBtn').addClass('btnSelect');
// hide other classes       
      $('.mon').addClass('hidden');
    });
 $('.g2-6Btn').click(function(){
// change btn color
      $('#g2-6Btn').removeClass('g2-6Btn').addClass('btnSelect');
// hide other classes       
      $('.g7-12').addClass('hidden');
    });
$('.g7-12Btn').click(function(){
 // change btn color
      $('#g7-12Btn').removeClass('g7-12Btn').addClass('btnSelect');
 // hide other classes      
     $('.g2-6').addClass('hidden');
    });
```

//  Clear Buttong Function

```
$('#clearBtn').click(function () {
if($('#thursBtn').hasClass('btnSelect')){
       $('#thursBtn').removeClass('btnSelect').addClass('thursBtn');}


if($('#monBtn').hasClass('btnSelect')){
       $('#monBtn').removeClass('btnSelect').addClass('monBtn');}

if($('#actBtn').hasClass('btnSelect')){
       $('#actBtn').removeClass('btnSelect').addClass('actBtn');}

if($('#voiceBtn').hasClass('btnSelect')){
       $('#voiceBtn').removeClass('btnSelect').addClass('voiceBtn');}

if($('#danceBtn').hasClass('btnSelect')){
       $('#danceBtn').removeClass('btnSelect').addClass('danceBtn');}

if($('#tchBtn').hasClass('btnSelect')){
       $('#tchBtn').removeClass('btnSelect').addClass('tchBtn');}

if($('#s1Btn').hasClass('btnSelect')){
       $('#s1Btn').removeClass('btnSelect').addClass('s1Btn');}

if($('#s2Btn').hasClass('btnSelect')){
       $('#s2Btn').removeClass('btnSelect').addClass('s2Btn');}

    if ($('.acting').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.acting').removeClass('hidden');
} 
    if ($('.sing').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.sing').removeClass('hidden');
} 
    if ($('.s1').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.s1').removeClass('hidden');
} 
    if ($('.s2').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.s2').removeClass('hidden');
} 
    if ($('.tech').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.tech').removeClass('hidden');
} 
    if ($('.dance').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.dance').removeClass('hidden');
} 
    if ($('.mon').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.mon').removeClass('hidden');
} 
    if ($('.thurs').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.thurs').removeClass('hidden');
} 
    if ($('.g2-6').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.g2-6').removeClass('hidden');
} 
    if ($('.g7-12').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.g7-12').removeClass('hidden');
} 
});
```

Comment: Js Fiddel https://jsfiddle.net/mplamp/cdh3gk18/

Comment: Unclear what you asking us to do. If you are asking us to write code for you, then that's not going to happen. If you want us to help fix your code, you're going to have to do a lot more explaining about what your code does. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: all I want to know is how to filter items so I can show just classes on mondays or session1 monday classes

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is that when you click a button of a specific filter, it will show/hide the div's that has that classes, right?

Considering that's what you want, pay attention that you want to do exactly the same thing with each button, and the only thing that changes is the list of classes affected for each filter, so to simplify the code we just really need one click function associated to all buttons, and inside of that function we will get that list.

My approach would be first create one object that has the relations between each button and the list of classes...

```
var relations = {
    actBtn: ['sing','tech','dance'],
    voiceBtn: ['acting','tech','dance'],
    danceBtn: ['sing','tech','acting'],
    tchBtn: ['sing','acting','dance'],
    ...
};
```

... I've used as the code for each filter the id's you're currently using. With this, you can create just one function to handle all buttons...

```
$('button').not('#clearBtn,#filterBtn').click(function() {

    // Change button color.
    $(this).toggleClass($(this).attr('id')+' btnSelect');

    if ($('button.btnSelect').length > 0) {

        // Hide all divs
        $('div.class').hide();

        // Show divs of all active filters.
        $('button.btnSelect').each(function() {
            $('.'+relations[$(this).attr('id')].join(',.')).show();
        });
    }
    else {
        $('div.class').show();
    }
});
```

As you can see, with this approach you can reduce your code considerably. For show/hide behaviours. Considering that you wnat to be able to activate multiple filters at the same time, and that they can share one or many classes, what I've done is everytime you hit a filter, first hide all divs and then check all active filters to show their corresponding classes, so you don't have to maintain any state.

And for the clear button...

```
$('button#clearBtn').click(function() {

    // Deactivate all buttons.
    $('button').removeClass('btnSelect').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass($(this).attr('id')))
            $(this).addClass($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    // Show all div's.
    $('.'+filters.join(',.')).show();
});
```

I don't understand why you add/remove the button class when you click on it (in fact, I don't see the point of that class, you already have the id with the same value), I've done it because you have it and maybe it has other relations, but I'd just add/remove the `btnSelect` class to indicate if the button is selected or not. I also don't see the point of the `Filter` button. I think you don't need it with this approach.

And it's easy to modify to adapt it to your preferences, because you only deal with one function.

I hope it helps